# Replace values in an sql query according to results of a nested query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables : request and location

Sample data for request

```
request id | requestor | locations
     1     |   ankur   |   2,5
     2     |   akshay  |   1  
     3     |   avneet  |   3,4
     4     |   priya   |   4
```

Sample data for locations

```
loc_id     |  loc_name |
     1     |  gondor   
     2     |  rohan
     3     |  mordor   
     4     |  bree   
     5     |  shire
```

I'd like to find the request_id for a particular location. If I do this with location_id, I am getting correct results.

```
select request_id from request where locations like "%,3%" or locations like "%3,%";
```

This query gives me the requests raised for location id = 3

How can I achieve this for loc_name instead? Replacing the digit in the "like" part of the query with

```
select loc_id from locations where loc_name = "mordor"
```

Any help with this would be very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()`

```
SELECT *
  FROM request r JOIN locations l
    ON FIND_IN_SET(loc_id, locations) > 0
 WHERE loc_name = 'mordor'
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/95b0a/2)** demo

But you **better normalize** your data by introducing a many-to-many table that may look like

```
CREATE TABLE request_location
(
  request_id INT NOT NULL,
  loc_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (request_id, loc_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (request_id) REFERENCES request (request_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (loc_id) REFERENCES locations (loc_id)
);
```

This will pay off big time in a long run enabling you to maintain and query your data normally.

Your query then may look like

```
SELECT *
  FROM request_location rl JOIN request r 
    ON rl.request_id = r.request_id JOIN locations l
    ON rl.loc_id = l.loc_id
 WHERE l.loc_name = 'mordor'
```

or even

```
SELECT rl.request_id
  FROM request_location rl JOIN locations l
    ON rl.loc_id = l.loc_id
 WHERE l.loc_name = 'mordor';
```

if you need to return only `request_id`

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1c4c5/1)** demo

Answer (score 1):

solution if locations is a varchar field!

join your tables with a like string (concat your r.locations for a starting and ending comma)

code is untested:

```
SELECT
    r.request_id
FROM location l
INNER JOIN request r
    ON CONCAT(',', r.locations, ',') LIKE CONCAT('%,',l.loc_id,',%')
WHERE l.loc_name = 'mordor'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
SELECT  *
FROM    request 
        CROSS JOIN
        (
        SELECT  1 AS loc
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  2 AS loc
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  3 AS loc
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  4 AS loc
        UNION ALL
        SELECT  5 AS loc
        ) q
JOIN    Location
ON      loc_id  = CAST(NULLIF(SUBSTRING_INDEX(locations, ',', -loc), SUBSTRING_INDEX(locations, ',', 1 - loc)) AS UNSIGNED)
```